# Typeahead in search box of ExtLib Application layout component

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I would like to provide typeahead suggestions when user enters few characters of his search in search box rendered by Application layout.

[image: Search box]

Our Application layout is used in many applications as shared custom control, so I am looking for solution which can be customized according to application it is in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SearchBar` is one of several "facets" supported by the `applicationLayout` component. When using the property panels to enable one or more of the "drop targets", Designer automatically adds markup like the following to the XML source:

```
<xe:applicationLayout>
    <xe:this.facets>
        <xp:callback facetName="facetRight" xp:key="RightColumn" />
        <xp:callback facetName="facetLeft" xp:key="LeftColumn" />
    </xe:this.facets>
```

For the benefit of those not familiar with the `callback` tag, this creates an Editable Area component, allowing any XPage (or Custom Control) containing your Custom Control to contribute its own content to it. If you were, for example, to add this Custom Control to an XPage and then use the Design tab to drag a Panel to the green dot representing the left column, you'd end up with markup like the following:

`<xp:panel xp:key="facetLeft" />`

So if you add an additional `callback` to the list of facets of your `applicationLayout`...

`<xp:callback facetName="facetSearch" xp:key="SearchBar" />`

...you'll have an additional drag target on any XPage to which you add your layout Custom Control. This ***replaces*** the standard search functionality of the `applicationLayout` with whatever content you drag into it. Hence, you can define your own custom search behavior in each application without affecting the rest of the standardized behavior of the `applicationLayout`.